# F# Literate pass arguments to script file

Tags: f#, f#-data, literate-programming, f#-scripting

I am using F# Formatting to do some [Literate](https://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Formatting/literate.html) programming.

My use case is that I have a couple of hundred data sets that I need to run through, and for each I want to create a "report" of some statistics and plots. They are all of the same format.

So what I want is to just have one fsx script file with F# code and markdown, that can be parsed in a loop to generate separate html files.

My current code looks like this:

```
// Create FSI evaluator with transformation enabling charts to show.
let fsiEval = FsiEvaluator() 
fsiEval.RegisterTransformation(transformation)
let source = __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__
let template = Path.Combine(source, "zeros.html")
let script = Path.Combine(source, "zeros.fsx")
Literate.ProcessScriptFile(script, templateFile = template, fsiEvaluator = fsiEval, output = "rendered.html")
```

This works fine, but I have to hard code which dataset I am looking at in the "zeros.fsx" file. I would like to pass parameters into this method:

```
Literate.ProcessScriptFile(script, templateFile = template, fsiEvaluator = fsiEval, output = "rendered.html")
```

so I can loop over it and generate all my different reports. But I can't find in the documentation how to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run arbitrary F# code using the `fsiEval` object before it runs the script, so one way to do this would be to write some code that defines a global variable, which will then be visible from the scripts (although, you will get an error in F# editor when editing the script...). Code to do this:

```
let fsiEval = FsiEvaluator() 
let ifsi = fsiEval :> IFsiEvaluator
ifsi.Evaluate("let magic = 40", false, None)
```

And my test file now shows the result as 42:

```
let res = 2 + magic
(*** include-value: res ***)
```

This works for configuration that you can reasonably pass via source code - I'm not sure if there is a good way of passing more complex objects around to the script.

Comment: Thank you Tomas. That will work excellent for my purposes. If one needed a complex object I guess one could just use a json string and go from there.